# Where can I purchase/download UCI Pro Tour/pro cycling race footage?

Tags: road-bike, training, racing, indoor

I love watching old races - they're especially great for long sessions on the trainer. However, I can find only a few stages/races on Youtube, and most of the videos are simply highlights. Where might I be able to purchase/download pro race footage (licitly)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a "shop for me" question

Comment: Please expound upon your reasoning.

Comment: @mikes I would say that "too broad" would be a better closure reason since every answer is likely to be equally valid.

Comment: @JohnRuffer The Q&A format of Stack Exchange sites means that the  best questions are those that have a single, best answer. Ideally, that answer will be good forever, or at least a very long time. This question has a couple of problems. 1) As I mentioned above, every answer a person puts up is likely to be equally valid. 2) If someone recommends a place and that place goes out of business, the answer is no longer valid. Incidentally, my local library stocks dvd's and has purchased old races at my request. They won't buy everything I ask for, but they do get some.

Comment: @jimirings That's reasonable. Thanks for the feedback. Alternatively, would there be a better place to ask such questions? No matter how great one's Google-Fu may be, there comes a point at which everyone could use a hand in their search for resources.

Comment: You could try our chat room. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome Although I have to admit that it's not currently heavily trafficked.

Answer (score 1):

There are sites such as [The Sufferfest](http://www.thesufferfest.com/) who do videos designed for trainers. I suspect there will be a bunch of these sites, you've probably found some already.

Also, some of the turbo manufacturers (I'm thinking particularly of Tacx since I have personal experience here) release DVDs which can be used in conjunction with your trainer. Tacx do two types - one is just a DVD that you watch while you pedal (and so is not restricted to Tacx trainers), the other is integrates with the Tacx software to give you a virtual reality experience (i.e. the speed at which you pedal governs the speed at which the video plays). But both are filmed in the first person, as if you're one of the riders, rather than being a commentary. See the Tacx site for more information - http://www.tacx.com/en/products/films. For the most part though these are courses rather than races, although there are some races and these are probably close to what you're looking for. But they work out very expensive.

Lastly I know the Tour de France release videos every year, but as you say these are highlight videos rather than full-length races.

But I don't know of anyone offering exactly what you're asking for I'm afraid. Certainly the European races, the spring classics etc, I'm pretty sure that videos don't exist. I mean, you can find loads of clips on YouTube but these are bits and bobs recorded off tv, I don't think you can get an "official" 4 or 5 hour dvd. I stand to be corrected...

Comment: Ah, yes, I use The Sufferfest quite often. I would just like to watch full races 1.) because they're nice white noise to put on during the day/evening and 2.) it's great to watch pros ride and learn from their technique. Unfortunately, it seems to be a bit more difficult to find full coverage race recordings than it would be to find, say, full football game recordings.

Comment: It is a shame I agree. I'm in the UK and its only the last couple of years that we've been able to watch the Classics, for example, live, courtesy of Eurosport TV. But they don't seem savvy enough to release them on DVD (or nowadays, online). You'd have thought editing the footage into something that could be distributed online would be money for old rope.

Comment: @JohnRuffer I don't know if you're still following this thread but have a look at [http://www.bromleyvideo.com/](http://www.bromleyvideo.com/). Their main downsode (for you) is that they're UK-based

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a swell resource. I appreciate the information.

Comment: @JohnRuffer also I have just discovered [cycling.tv](http://www.cycling.tv/HomePage.dbml?SPSID=104955&SPID=12555&DB_OEM_ID=20300) - not sure whether I'll subscribe yet although it looks cheap enough, we have daily cycling on "regular" tv at the moment.